# LINQ Select statement with EF - object initializer reuse assignment

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-6

I have a case in my application where I create selects over an `IQueryable` in this manner:

```
myContext.Data
    .Where(...)
    .OrderBy(...)
    .Select(p => new MyDataModel()
    {
        ...
        MyComplexProp = p.SomeProp.HasValue ? p.OtherProp.Name + " " + p.AnotherProp.Mark : p.EvenAnotherProp.Name,
        ...
    });
```

Now, the assignment to `MyComplexProp` is used on multiple places and I'd like to extract it to a single place so I can reuse it. Does anyone have an idea on how to achieve this?

I cannot use a static method because the `IQueryable` must not be executed in this phase.

Comment: If `Data` contains `MyDataModel` then just define `MyComplexProp` as a calculated property in a partial class file and remove the `.Select()` section - instead add a `.List()`.

Comment: I can't put the calculated property on the entity because you can't use them in a Select over an IQueryable. Calling ToList is not an option

Comment: Did you try to use extension method?

Comment: Extensions methods are also static, they cannot be used

Comment: @MateoVelenik Unless you are using the value in a query condition, there is no cause for not using it after the final .ToList(). If you using the value in a query condition, a. don't, b. you can use a view.

Answer (score 1):

Add a new constructor to `MyDataModel` to take the entity as an argument and do the logic:

```
public class MyDataModel
{
    public string MyComplexProp {get; set;}

    //Include a default constructor
    public MyDataModel()
    {
    }

    //Include a default constructor
    public MyDataModel(DataClass data)
    {
        MyComplexProp = data.SomeProp.HasValue ? data.OtherProp.Name + " " + data.AnotherProp.Mark : data.EvenAnotherProp.Name,
    }
}
```

Then your linq would simplify to:

```
myContext.Data
    .Where(...)
    .OrderBy(...)
    .AsEnumerable()
    .Select(p => new MyDataModel(p));
```

Note the use of the AsEnumerable(). This will mean that the constructor can execute in memory, but you will still have deferred execution of the query.

To acheive full DB side execution you'll need the logic converted to an expression. You're probably into creating an expression tree.

Comment: that works for in-memory selections, but you can't use constructors with parameters in LINQ-to-Entities

Comment: Have modified slightly. Think this is the best you'll do without a bunch of extra work with Expressions.

Comment: @Kamyar: It won't be - see the difference between AsEnumerable and ToList

Comment: I'm reading about AsEnumerable now - thanks for the suggestion, I'll try and see what kind of SQL it generates. Unfortunately I think the only solution that will fit will be building the expression tree myself

Answer (score 0):

I've already tested Extension Method for your question and It works.
Here is the sample code:

```
namespace MyExtensionMethods
{
    //MyDataModel sample
    public class MyDataModel
    {
        public int? SomeProp { get; set; }
        public string OtherPropName { get; set; }
        public string AnotherPropMark { get; set; }
        public string EvenAnotherPropName { get; set; }
    }

    //The extension Method
    public static class ExtensionMethod
    {
        public static string ToMyComplexProp(this MyDataModel p)
        {
            return p.SomeProp.HasValue ? p.OtherPropName + " " + p.AnotherPropMark : p.EvenAnotherPropName;
        }
    }

    public class TestClass
    {
        MyDataModel myDataModel;
        public TestClass()
        {
            myDataModel = new MyDataModel();
            //This is the extension method and it's working
            myDataModel.ToMyComplexProp();
        }
    }
}
```

If you tried extension methods and it didn't work for you, the you declared it incorrectly. The soul purpose of extension method is for situations like this (Like how Linq is using it).

I suggest you to check [MSDN Extension Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/bb383977.aspx) example to use it properly.

Comment: as I stated before, this is a Entity Framework related question - and static methods cannot be translated into SQL. Your solution is OK for in memory execution which is not an acceptable option for my case.